# Custom Column Names having spaces Laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

I want to use a custom column name that has spaces.How can I write the query for this using Laravel 4.
I tried

```
$org = Org::select('name as Organization Name')->where('id',$user->orgId);
$org = Org::select('name as "Organization Name"')->where('id',$user->orgId);
$org = Org::select('name as `Organization Name`')->where('id',$user->orgId);
$org = Org::select('name as (Organization Name)')->where('id',$user->orgId);
$org = Org::select('name as {Organization Name}')->where('id',$user->orgId);
```

Nothing gave me the solution..

Comment: Suggestion: It is a bad practicse to give spaces in the table column names, instead  use  `_ ` wherever you need to use spaces in the database table columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried using raw ?

```
Org::select(DB::raw('name as `Organization Name`, status'))->where('id',$user->orgId);
```